# Cant open file for writing with cifs mount

Tags: ubuntu, mount, smb, fstab, cifs

Hi I have mounted my QNAP on to a drive on my ubuntu machine using the following fstab entry

```
//<ip-address>/Documents/Aly /home/aly/Documents cifs credentials=/root/.credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,hard,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
```

this gives the following permisssions:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 aly aly    0 2011-12-03 12:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 aly aly 4096 2011-12-03 12:14 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 aly aly    5 2011-12-03 11:55 test.tst
drwxrwxrwx  1 aly aly    0 2011-11-26 17:54 VirtualBox VMs
```

I have permissions to delete files and add files, however when trying to write to a file i.e. test.tst I get the following error in vi:

```
"test.tst" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

Has anyone seen this before, if i mount the drive via nfs this is not an issue, however nfs lacks the security i desire.

**EDIT**

The solution I have come to is:

```
<ip-address>:Documents/Aly/ /home/aly/Documents cifs hard,noperm,nouid,credentials=/root/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nodfs 0 0
```

Comment: What does `mount` show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the `nodfs` parameter (if supported) as explained in the article
[How to workaround the DFS samba bug on the DNS323 NAS ?](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/dsn323-samba-dfs-bug/start) :

> Firstly, here is a quick bug description: It's impossible to modify
>   any existing files. The "Not a directory" or "No such file or
>   directory" or "touch: setting times of…" errors occurs when trying to
>   modify a file.
>
> If your linux cifs or smbfs client support the nodfs flag (integrated
>   in kernels > 2.6.27). You just have to add this option to the mount
>   command. Example:

```
mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/kerphi/.smb-zekra-credentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nodfs //zekra/Volume_1 /home/kerphi/zekra
```

> If you cannot upgrade your kernel (like me because i'm following the debian releases), you have to follow this workaround:
>
> - Connect to the DNS323 using the web GUI and goto tools→system.
> - Save the configuration to your workstation (in "CONFIGURATION SETTINGS" section).
> - After saving edit the file and just under this line:
>     `;[ global ]`
>     add the following line:
>     `msdfs root = no`
>     Then upload this file through the web interface, your NAS will reboot and you will be able to modify existing file again !

This is further explained in [CIFS: Add nodfs mount option](http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/PATCH-CIFS-Add-nodfs-mount-option-td2520594.html) :

> Older samba server (eg. 3.0.24 from Debian etch) don't work correctly,
>   if DFS paths are used. Such server claim that they support DFS, but
>   fail to process some requests with DFS paths. Starting with Linux
>   2.6.26, the cifs clients starts sending DFS paths in such situations, rendering it unuseable with older samba servers.
>
> The nodfs mount options forces a share to be used with non DFS paths,
>   even if the server claims, that it supports it.

Comment: No luck with this approach either :(

Comment: What is your take on these : [link1](http://www.ozzu.com/unix-linux-forum/mount-cifs-permission-denied-mount-smbfs-works-fine-t99920.html) and [link2](http://lists.samba.org/archive/linux-cifs-client/2006-November/001590.html).

Comment: Hi Thanks I seem to have it working - will edit my question with the solution and mark yours as correct as it provided me with all the info. A well deserved bounty!

Answer (score 0):

> when trying to write to a file

Write with root privilidges, then it will most probably work (`rw` options given)